# How to keep the carriage return by Ignoring the carriage return C#

Tags: c#

I thank you in advance.

I have a function that removes any number of characters past the maximum length. However, it also removes carriage returns. So, if I write a paragraph and use carriage returns for the new paragraph the carriage returns would also be counted and removed.

Does anybody have a good idea how I can achieve removing anything over the maximum length of characters without removing or counting the carriage returns?

```
    public static string RemoveExcessCharacters(string value, int maxLen)
    {
        return (value.Length > maxLen) ? value.Substring(0, maxLen) : value;
    }
```

The input code. Some of the code I was just testing like. newString in the code.

```
        private void txtWrite_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int g = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbersOnly.Text);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNumbersOnly.Text) || g == 0)
            {
                txtWrite.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide character Count. Character Count cannot be zero or Null.", "Maximum Characters", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtNumbersOnly.Text = "777";
                txtNumbersOnly.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                cCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbersOnly.Text);
                if (cCount == 0)
                {
                    txtWrite.Text = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("Please provide character Count. Character Count cannot be zero.", "Maximum Characters", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    txtNumbersOnly.Focus();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Testing again
                    //x = txtWrite.Text.TrimEnd();
                    x = txtWrite.Text;
                    //var newString = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(x, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)")).Length;
                    //var newString = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(x, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)")).Length;
                    //string v = x.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
                    string cleaned = x;
                    string cleaned2 = cleaned.Length.ToString();
                    int cleaned3 = Convert.ToInt32(cleaned2);
                    lblChar.Text = "Character Count: " + cleaned2;
                    //
                    if (cleaned3 > cCount)
                    {
                        string strTest = x.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show("You are over the maximum character length.\nI will trim this down for you now.", "Maximum Character Length", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        int intTrans = Convert.ToInt32(x.Length);
                        if (intTrans > cCount)
                        {
                            // Remove ending Characters over the max amount.
                            string value = RemoveExcessCharacters(txtWrite.Text, cCount);
                            // Re-add corrected text to the textbox.
                            txtWrite.Text = value;
                            // Move cursor to end
                            txtWrite.SelectionStart = txtWrite.Text.Length;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            //
            return;
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide example inputs and outputs for a single line and multi-line input string?

Comment: why not just a `string.replace` on the string being checked before you test the length?

Comment: Thank you. I just provided example inputs.

Comment: Are you aware that `\r` is a carriage return and `\n` is the newline character? Have you read your own code? `string v = x.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");` removes both those characters completely, so either you intentionally want to remove them, or you've made a terrible mistake. I'm having trouble with your question being about ignoring the newline while your code intentionally removes them. Can you provide some clarity?

Comment: Yes, but even when I did not remove (x = txtWrite.Text) them it still did not work in the function to ignore the carriage return or line feeds etc.

Comment: Then provide the rest of your code, in the form of a [mre] that we can copy/paste and run to reproduce the issue. And you've still not explained why your question doesn't match what your code is doing. Are you trying to **keep** the newlines by ignoring them, or do you want to **remove** the newlines, which is what your code does?

Comment: Okay, the textbox code has been updated. Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. So what I'm trying to say is if I write a paragraph and have a carriage return for the new paragraph. Currently, the code will remove the carriage returns and not keep the formatting. I figured the best way to do that would be to ignore the carriage returns; not count them in the remove function.

Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty trying to figure that one out.

Comment: I asked you an either/or question, and your response is *Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.*? It's one or the other, and you need to edit your post and make it clear which ONE of those things it is that you're asking. I've asked *Do you want chicken or steak?*, and you've said *Yes*, which does not help when I'm shopping for dinner. It's one or the other. What do you want to be placed on your plate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. You asked... Are you trying to keep the newlines by ignoring them? This was the yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on my other answer it seems you want a remove function that ignores certain characters when it is removing. `"this is some text".RemoveIgnoring(6, " \r\n")` produces "this is"

```
public static string RemoveIgnoring(this string original, int howMany, string ignore){
  var sb = new StringBuilder();

  for(; howMany > 0 && sb.Length < original.Length; howMany -= ignore.Contains(original[sb.Length-1])? 0:1)
    sb.Append(original[sb.Length]);

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The way it works is to loop over the string accumulating characters into a StringBuilder but it only decrements howMany if the char does not appear in the `ignore` string. It means that eg spaces or new lines are "free" additions whereas everything else "costs 1", eventually all the "money" (the `howMany` variable) is used up

Comment: Note that this is an extension method; it should be placed in a static class. It adds itself to any string/you call it like you would call string.Remove or string.Substring

Answer (score 0):

Don't cut the end off the user's words; stackoverflow doesn't when you write a comment - it just counts down the chars you have left and let's you exceed but doesn't submit. This is nicer because it's not arbitrarily deciding to delete what the user typed

As such, a simple button click submit validation of:

```
public void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  if(someTextBox.Text.Count(c => !"\r\n".Contains(c)) > 500)
    MessageBox.Show("You have exceeded 500 chars, not including new lines. Shorten your message before you submit");
  else
    SubmitMessage(someTextBox.Text);
}
```

You can apply the same technique to the TextChanged event if you want to eg provide a label that constantly counts down as the user types

Comment: Thank you. However, the actual part I'm having the biggest problem with is returning the excess characters but not counting carriage returns or a space. For example

This is some text
string value = "";
strOnCount = value.Remove(6);

I needed 6 characters to be returned excluding the carriage return; "This is". The remove function will remove anything after character six including the carriage returns or spaces.